# Extracting particular nested properties with a $ prefix in Amazon Redshift or Quicksight

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift, amazon-quicksight

I am using PostHog for product analytics and have exported some event data to Amazon Redshift as well as S3 to be used in Quicksight.

Under the personal properties part of the JSON, each individual property is nested but begins with a `$`

I am quite new to SQL queries as well as getting specific details from JSON. in Quicksight using `parseJson`

Here is an example of the JSON from PostHog

```
"properties": {
    "$active_feature_flags": [],
    "$browser": "Chrome",
    "$browser_version": 98,
    "$ce_version": 1,
    "$device_type": "Desktop",
    "$environment": "test",
    "$event_type": "click",
    "$lib": "web",
    "$lib_version": "1.17.8",
    "$os": "Mac OS X",
    "$pathname": "/events",
    "$plugins_deferred": [],
    "$plugins_failed": [],
    "$plugins_succeeded": [
        "First Event Today (4914)",
        "GeoIP (5539)"
    ],
```

I have sought help from a few sources who have mentioned it isn't as simple because of the `$` symbol at the beginning.

So my question would be,

1. How would I query this in Redshift to successfully extract `$device_type` and `$os` for example?
2. How would I pull the same properties using `parseJson` in Amazon Quicksight?

Answer (score 0):

I can answer #1.

The json provided looks to be a snippet and invalid as is.  So I removed the trailing ',' and used SQL to provide the surrounding '{}'.  Once it is valid json this runs fine:

```
create table test as select '"properties": {
    "$active_feature_flags": [],
    "$browser": "Chrome",
    "$browser_version": 98,
    "$ce_version": 1,
    "$device_type": "Desktop",
    "$environment": "test",
    "$event_type": "click",
    "$lib": "web",
    "$lib_version": "1.17.8",
    "$os": "Mac OS X",
    "$pathname": "/events",
    "$plugins_deferred": [],
    "$plugins_failed": [],
    "$plugins_succeeded": [
        "First Event Today (4914)",
        "GeoIP (5539)"
    ]
}' as json_text;

select json_extract_path_text('{' || json_text  ||'}', 'properties' ,'$device_type') as device_type,
                json_extract_path_text('{' || json_text  ||'}', 'properties' ,'$os') as os
from test;
```